# I'm using realm DB and it has no Foreign keys .. is there any alternative solution?

Tags: android, mysql, database, realm, realm-java

guys i'm working on a android project for my DB course and i'm using realm DB but the problem is that i just found that realm has no foreign keys(realm is NOT a relational DB) so i was wondering if there is any other solution to use as a foreign key?

i was thinking about using class composition but would it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm has the concept of "relationships" (otherwise called as "links").

To-one relationship:

```
public class A extends RealmObject {
    B b;
}
```

To many relationship:

```
public class A extends RealmObject {
    RealmList<B> bs;
}
```

And for either of those relationships, there exists an inverse relationship (Realm Java 3.5.0+)

```
public class A extends RealmObject {
    B b;

    RealmList<B> bs;
}

public class B extends RealmObject {
    @LinkingObjects("b")
    private final RealmResults<B> fromB = null;

    @LinkingObjects("bs")
    private final RealmResults<B> fromBs = null;
}
```

---

If an object is unmanaged, then `insertOrUpdate()`/`copyToRealmOrUpdate()` will insert both `A` and its instance `B` into the Realm.

If an object is managed, then the object you set as value must be managed as well.

```
A a = realm.createObject(A.class);
a.setB(realm.createObject(B.class)); // or copyToRealmOrUpdate(b) or .findFirst() etc
```